# how to generate static file from react js by using vite js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

when I generate a static file of react js from vite js it shows just a blank page.
I don't know, Is this happening bcz of vite app, or is something wrong with the package.json configuration?
i also added homepage property in package.json file but same issue

Vite.config.js

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
 plugins: [react()],
 base:"./"
})
```

App.js

```
import {BrowserRouter,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from './Layouts/Navbar'
import BecomeInfluncer from './Pages/BecomeInfluncer'
import Home from './Pages/Home'
import ErrorPage from './Pages/ErrorPage'
import PrivacyPolicy from './Pages/PrivacyPolicy'
import TermCondition from './Pages/TermCondition'
function App() {
  

  return (
    <>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
            <Route path='/influencer' element={<BecomeInfluncer/>} />
            <Route path='/term-condition' element={<TermCondition />} />
            <Route path='/privacy-policy' element={<PrivacyPolicy/>} />
            <Route path='*' element={<ErrorPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  )
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "azgarty",
  "homepage": "/",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.4.3",
    "swiper": "^8.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "postcss": "^8.4.17",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "vite": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "static file"? Are you building your app with `npm run build` or trying to use vite in development mode `npm run dev`?

Comment: yes static file mean " npm run build "